# Modifying Active Directory logonHours attribute over LDAP?

Tags: active-directory, ldap

I need to change the logonHours attribute in Active Directory over LDAP, eg. using ldapmodify. The attribute is of type byte string.

Is this possible?

Comment: Are you asking if ldapmodify can modify the attribute?  If you have ldapmodify, you can easily try and modify an account.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use base64 encoding of the binary string in your LDAP change.  The `::` specifies that the value is base64 encoded.

So, here's the base64 encoded version of 21 bytes of `11111111`, to allow login always:

```
logonHours:: ////////////////////////////
```

And here's `00000000`, for never:

```
logonHours:: AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
```

And, say, 9 to 5 on Monday through Friday:

```
logonHours:: AAAAAAD/AAD/AAD/AAD/AAD/AAAA
```